# Поворот текстуры и движение на определённый угол Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity3d, случайные-числа

Есть текстура, бегает в неком радиуса, стукаясь об стенки - получает новое направление.

```
Vector2 dir;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("Move", 1 / 24f, 1 / 24f);
    dir = Vector2.right;
}

void Update() 
{

}

void Move()
{      
    transform.Translate(dir);       
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{       

    if (coll.name.StartsWith("bright"))
    {
        dir = -Vector2.right;          
    }
    if (coll.name.StartsWith("bleft"))
    { 
        dir = Vector2.right;            
    }

    if (coll.name.StartsWith("btop"))
    { 
        dir = Vector2.down; 
    }       
}
```

Хочу чтобы текстура бегала не (вверх\низ\лево\право) а на определённый угол
Пробовал так

```
dir = Vector(0, 1);
```

Но подчёркивает красным. Как на 45* допустим повернуть?

А соответственный вопрос - как повернуть на случайный угол? 
На случайный, кроме допустим, 0?

Comment: Именно повернуть? Или чтоб движение было в рандомную сторону? Вы арканойд делаете?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Чтоб после удара о стенку оно улетело в другую рандомную сторону, но не через стенку( т.е. не полный рандом а с исключениями)
И поворот текстуры тоже интересует, чтоб был трансформ на те же градусы что и отлетает. Делаю типо арканоида, но проще, изучаю пока Unity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1)** Конструкция вида `dir = Vector(0, 1);` не работает потому, что нужно писать `Vector2/Vector3`, а не просто `Vector`. И так как вы не обращаетесь к свойству как здесь

```
Vector2.down;
```

то значит надо обращаться к экземпляру класса, т.е. надо писать

```
dir = new Vector2(0, 1);
```

**2)** Даже если писать `new Vector2(0, 1)` в теории он должен полететь строго  вверх, но никак не под углом. Для этого нужно объект либо повернуть, либо так и указать `new Vector2(1, 1)`, т.е. лететь вверх и вправо, т.е. под углом

**3)** При отскоке от сторон на одинаковый угол достаточно помнить, что при достижении какой-либо стороны - скорость меняется на противоположную (без учета сил трения, сил отскока и прочего). А-ля угол падения равен углу отражения. А значит при достижении правой или левой стороны (то есть ось X), достаточно изменить направление движение на противоположное для данной оси: `X = -X;`. А так как по вертикали он (объект) итак будет двигаться в заданном направлении, то получится отскок на угол. С отскоком по вертикали все точно также.

Из вышесказанного следует:

```
Vector2 dir;
Transform myTransform;

public float vx = 1f;
public float vy = 1f;
public float speed = 1f;

void Start() {      
    //InvokeRepeating("Move", 0.07f, 0.07f);
    myTransform =transform;
    dir = new Vector2(vx, vy);
}

void Update() {     
    myTransform.Translate(dir * speed * Time.deltaTime); 
}

//  void Move() { transform.Translate(dir * speed * Time.deltaTime); }

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {

    if (coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("bright") || coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("bleft")) {
        vx = -vx;
    }

    if (coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("btop") || coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("bbottom")) { 
        vy = -vy;
    }   

    dir = new Vector2(vx, vy);          
}
```

**4)** По поводу рандома. Можно использовать две вещи

- Собственно класс из .Net: [System.Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)
- Из Unity: [Random.Range](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) - который сгенерирует число в заданном диапазоне

Например вместо

```
vx = -vx;
```

можно написать

```
var sign = Mathf.Sign(vx);
var random = Random.Range(1f, 2f);

vx = random * sign * -1;
```

`vx` примет значение в диапазоне от 1 до 2.
`sign` - нужен здесь, чтоб установить корректно значение `vx`, ибо мы не знаем в данный момент времени какое значение у него имеется: положительное или отрицательное. А так берем знак, генерируем число, присваиваем его с противоположным знаком.

**5)** По поводу углов поворота у Юнити есть много различных вариантов и это проще все вычитать самому.
Кто-то делает разные параметры X и Y и в результате достигается угол, кто-то использует [transform.localRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localRotation.html), кто-то метод [transform.Rotate()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html). Есть вот даже пример:

```js
 public class FollowPath: MonoBehaviour {


   public float speed;
   public float rotationSpeed;
   //transform
   Transform myTrans;
   //object position
   Vector3 myPos;
   //object rotation
   Vector3 myRot;
   //object rotation 
   float angle;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start() {
     myTrans = transform;
     myPos = myTrans.position;
     myRot = myTrans.rotation.eulerAngles;
   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void FixedUpdate() {

     //converting the object euler angle's magnitude from to Radians    
     angle = myTrans.eulerAngles.magnitude * Mathf.Deg2Rad;


     //rotate object Right & Left
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
       myRot.z -= rotationSpeed;
     }
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
       myRot.z += rotationSpeed;
     }


     //move object Forward & Backward
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {

       myPos.x += (Mathf.Cos(angle) * speed) * Time.deltaTime;
       myPos.y += (Mathf.Sin(angle) * speed) * Time.deltaTime;
     }
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
       myPos.x += Mathf.Cos(angle) * Time.deltaTime;
       myPos.y += Mathf.Sin(angle) * Time.deltaTime;
     }


     //Apply
     myTrans.position = myPos;
     myTrans.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(myRot);

   }
 }
```

Где само движение построено на вычислении угла и подстановке в `transform.position`

```
 myPos.x += (Mathf.Cos (angle) * speed) * Time.deltaTime;
 myPos.y += (Mathf.Sin (angle) * speed) * Time.deltaTime;
```

Для вашего примера можно попробовать что-то такое:

```
private Vector2 dir;
private Transform myTransform;

public float speed;
public float angle;
public float vx = 1;
public float vy = 1;

void Start() {
    myTransform = transform;
    InvokeRepeating("Move", 0.05f, 0.05f);

    dir = Vector2.right;

    angle = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.right, new Vector2(vx, vy));
    myTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
}

void Move() {      
    myTransform.Translate(dir * speed * Time.deltaTime);    
}


void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {     
    if (coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith ("bright") || coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("bleft")) {           
        vx = -vx;
    }

    if (coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith ("btop") || coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("bbottom")) {           
        vy = -vy;
    }

    angle = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.right, new Vector2(vx, vy));
    if (coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith ("bleft") && vy < 0 || coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith ("bright") && vy < 0 || coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("btop")) {           
        angle = -angle;
    }

    myTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но лучше подольше почитать про вращения и как их оптимизировать и применить к себе.

Comment: Спасибо, всё понятно. При попытке запустить ваш код объект двигается очень очень медленно, причем редактирование переменной speed ничего не дает. Зато, если заменить Time.deltatime на что 0.5f(speed при этом так же 1f, хотя даже при 500f ничего не меняется) то скорость станет нормальной. Зачем вообще Time.deltatime? Я так понял что это время между кадрами, но зачем оно тут?

Comment: @Dmitrii Зависит от размеров объекта и масштаба. для моего масштаба все нормально. Так что тут надо играться... возможно в чем-то другом проблема........`deltaTime` это время которое потребовалось для прохождения последнего кадра. Его стоит использовать только для определения величины в одном кадре которую нужно изменять, чтобы например плавно переместить объект. Если этого не делать, то в зависимости от производительности компьютера или другого устройства - у кого-то будет быстро двигаться, у кого-то медленно... Поэтому как минимум для движения он должен присутствовать.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз! А вот вопрос - иногда при повороте направление курсора не совпадает с нужным. А иногда - совпадает. Может ли это быть из за минусового значения между Vector2.right; и new Vector2(vx, vy). И как это лечить.

Comment: @Dmitrii честно говоря не понял, что за курсор. Ось X объекта? Ну вроде логично, что если объект вращается, то его направленные вращаются  с ним. Это как нарисовать систему координат на листке бумаги и вращать листок. Все стрелки тоже начнут смещаться. Или вы смотрите вперед, а если будете делать кувырок, то будете быстрое движение картинки. Во время кувырка глаза не будут видеть постоянно картинку, что и до в стоячем положении)) .... А вот глобальная системы координат остается неизменной. В данном случае окно Юнити

Comment: Я понял! `angle = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.right, new Vector2(vx, vy));` меняет так же полную ориентацию трансформы, поэтому у меня оно не только поворачиваеться на нужный градус а еще и двигается туда!
А можно как нибудь только текстуру повернуть?

Comment: @Dmitrii Ну разве что сделать так: создать `GameObject` пустой. На него навесить контроллер. А у этого объекта сделать дочерним другой объект, у которого, как раз, и будет `SpriteRender()` и прочие атрибуты спрайта (так как раз и делают в играх управления персонажем..всегда есть пустой объект обертка). Вот только как код будет выглядеть так сходу не скажу.